# SUM all timeelapse WHERE timetype = 'Break' but only the rows that are after(below) timetype = 'Start'

Tags: postgresql, function, sum

))Hi all, This is my table...

[image]

This is the SQL statement to create the same table...

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_ebscbspa_log05
(
  pcnum smallint NOT NULL,
  fnserial serial NOT NULL,
  fnname character varying NOT NULL,
  timestmp timestamp without time zone DEFAULT clock_timestamp(),
  timeelapse interval,
  timetype character varying,
  timeindex real,
  CONSTRAINT table_ebscb_spa_log05_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fnserial)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE tbl_ebscbspa_log05
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

How can I SUM all timeelapse WHERE timetype = 'Break' AND that are placed after(below) the last(descendent) timetype = 'Start'? So in the table above Ill get both blue square colored rows summed up. So I get 'totalbreak' = 00-00-00 02:00:00.000

How would be the syntax to select all possible 'Breaks' after the last(descendent) 'Start' and sum them up? (lets say the max possible 'Breaks' are nine).

I have try this, resulting NULL

```
SELECT t.timeelapse FROM tbl_ebscbspa_log05 t WHERE t.timetype = 'Break' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_ebscbspa_log05 WHERE timetype = 'Start' AND 'timestmp' > 't.timestmp') INTO v_timeelapse_break;
        IF FOUND THEN
          NEW.timeelapse := v_timeelapse_break;
```

Pls I would like to know how to SUM THEM UP, not just SELECT THEM, hope some good PostgreSQL fellow programmer could give me a hand with it.

Thanks Advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(timeelapse)
FROM tbl_ebscbspa_log05
WHERE timetype = 'Break'
  AND fnserial > 
    /* Get serial of last record with timetyoe 'Start' */
   ( SELECT max( fnserial )
      FROM tbl_ebscbspa_log05
      WHERE timetype = 'Start'
    )
```

Comment: Hi @kordirko, thanks, it worked, though Im worry about the performance, Ive read that MAX() could run slow and that this... SELECT t.timeelapse FROM tbl_ebscbspa_log05 t WHERE t.timetype = 'Break' AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl_ebscbspa_log05 WHERE timetype = 'Start' AND 'timestmp' > 't.timestmp')... will run faster, on really huge amounts of INSERTS, but I can't get it to work, any idea? ThanksAdvanced.

Comment: I think the error is here: `... 'timestmp' > 't.timestmp'...`. You are using string literals `'timestamp'` and `'t.timestmp'` instead of column names => just `....timestmp > t.timestmp ...` without aphostrophes. When something is enclosed within aphostrophes, then it is treated as **a string literal** (simply: string), not a column name. Out of curiosity - where have you read that MAX() could run slow ? When proper indexes are in place, then it run really fast - for the query from my naswer create an index on `tbl_ebscbspa_log05( timetype, fnserial)` and MAX() will run in a few miliseconds.

Comment: No, I don't have any index. If my fnserial column has 9000 rows, SELECT MAX(fnserial) means that it will check through all 9000 rows to see which is higher??

Comment: what about... `SELECT SUM(timeelapse) FROM table WHERE timetype = 'Break' AND fnserial > (SELECT fnserial FROM table WHERE timetype = 'Start' ORDER BY fnserial DESC LIMIT 1)`... wouldn't it be faster? would it check through all 9000 rows?